# How to repair a failed solid state drive

Tags: windows, hard-drive, ssd, windows-8.1, repair

I had an internal SSD fail on me after 2 years of use (a Micron C400 512GB SSD). I wanted to try and repair it myself.

Dismantling it is easy. Things look good; physically the board is super clean and nothing seems "off" for lack of a better word, but then again I have untrained eyes. What are some things I can look for, and what are some ways in which I can try to repair it?

I mean, how do the data recovery experts generally go about fixing these devices? I would like to try my hand at fixing this device myself. I don't think its due to the MTBF, the MTBF is rated at 1.2 million device hours and I really don't think I hit that, nor had it been used too much; I never usually download directly to it.

For sure the drive did fail though, as I ran an ePSA boot and it failed testing on it. Also, it had the latest firmware and I tried power cycling it multiple times. Its dead, like dead-dead, like tombstone dead.

Comment: It's called Mean Time Between Failures because that's the mean. You could have very well just hit a faulty one.

Comment: SSD drives have a theoretical maximum number of writes that can be performed before a cell gets degraded.  Another factor for failure is due to the manufacturing process certain "cells" can be created faulty which can also create problems.

Comment: This might be better suited for [Electrical Engineering Stack Exchange](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/). Its a rather open-ended question, so you might have trouble with it on any site in the SE network.